# Keep an Item at the top of a list view

Tags: android, listview

is there a way in android to make it so that an item or title type item sits at the top of the view of a list view? I want a section title to sit at the top of the visible part of the list view until the next one comes to the top and replaces it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [PinnedHeaderListView](https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView) and the [android-amazing-listview](https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/) projects. They both provider ListViews with pinned header capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this library PinnedHeaderListView

github.com/mldeng/PinnedHeaderListView

This will definetely help you achieve exactly what you want.